# Confusing output from Python cProfile - queue and threading

Tags: python, performance-testing, profiler

I'm trying to find performance bottlenecks in a Python application.  The crux of the app is reading data from a text file and inserting it into and RDBMS.  I'm using direct ODBC SQL and the program is single-threaded.  I do not use the threading or queue libraries at all.

Output from cProfile is below.  I'm trying to figure out how the majority of the execution time is taken up by queue.py, builtins.exec and threading.py.  Any suggestions are most appreciated.
'''

```
    6617261 function calls (6606203 primitive calls) in 149.445 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
2445/1461    0.042    0.000  278.930    0.191 queue.py:154(get)
      3/1    0.046    0.015  149.242  149.242 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     2433   36.848    0.015  148.912    0.061 threading.py:302(wait)
      983    0.081    0.000   73.227    0.074 threading.py:616(wait)
  1007188   19.456    0.000   19.567    0.000 functions.py:53(sql_val)
     6002   13.408    0.002   13.408    0.002 {method 'execute' of 'pyodbc.Cursor' objects}
     6001    6.708    0.001    6.708    0.001 {method 'commit' of 'pyodbc.Cursor' objects}
       19    0.001    0.000    3.833    0.202 pydevd_net_command.py:102(send)
    29609    0.108    0.000    2.874    0.000 {built-in method strptime}
    29609    0.417    0.000    2.766    0.000 _strptime.py:552(_strptime_datetime)
    29609    1.729    0.000    2.349    0.000 _strptime.py:293(_strptime)
    25676    0.287    0.000    0.740    0.000 locale.py:250(currency)
    29611    0.058    0.000    0.437    0.000 _strptime.py:26(_getlang)
    29611    0.086    0.000    0.379    0.000 locale.py:580(getlocale)
  2015091    0.361    0.000    0.361    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
    51352    0.034    0.000    0.316    0.000 locale.py:108(localeconv)
```

'''

Comment: The culprit appears to be VS Code.  When I run the application directly from the command line performance improves by a factor > 100.